# How to sum a column in laravel when exported to excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am writing a laravel application and I want to export my product table to excel but I dont know how to go about it.

I am using maatwebsite-excel

Here is my code

```
class ClientExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithColumnWidths
{
    use Exportable;
    public function columnWidths(): array
    {
        return [
            'A' => 10,
            'B' => 35,            
            'C' => 35,            
            'D' => 35,            
            'E' => 35,            
            'F' => 35                   
        ];
    }
    public function collection()
    {
        return AdminClient::query()->get([
                    'id',
                    'name',
                    'product',
                    'price',
                    'qty',
                    'total'
                ])
            ;;
    }
public function headings(): array
{
    return [
        'id',
        'name',
        'product',
        'price',
        'qty',
        'total'
    ];
}
```

I want to get the sum of price, qty and total column when exported to excel

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the  package  works,but this might help you.
try to add a custom attribute to your model
//AdminClient

```
public function getTotalAttribute(){
   return $this->qty*$this->price;
}
```

and then add the attribute to model `protected $appends =['total']`

your model should have additional attribute which is `total`

Comment: I have done that. I want to get the total of each column.